# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - Line 17

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm practicing javascript and I stopped at this part, I didn't understand the error, I'm new to the language, someone help me?

```
const a = 10;
const b = 33;

function sum(a, b){
    return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);  
}

document.querySelector("#calculate").addEventListener("click", function(){
    let valueA = document.querySelector("#valueA").value;
    let valueB = document.querySelector("#valueB").value;

    if(valueA.length > 0 && valueB.length > 0){   
        alert sum(valueA, valueB);
    }else{
        alert("Enter a value for to the calculation!");  
        }
});
```

Comment: `alert sum(valueA, valueB);` this is invalid - you probably meant `alert(sum(valueA, valueB));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alert sum(valueA, valueB);`

should be

`alert(sum(valueA, valueB));`

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @VLAZ .

Working example:

```js
const a = 10;
const b = 33;

function sum(a, b){
    return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);  
}

document.querySelector("#calculate").addEventListener("click", function(){
    let valueA = document.querySelector("#valueA").value;
    let valueB = document.querySelector("#valueB").value;

    if(valueA.length > 0 && valueB.length > 0){   
        alert (sum(valueA, valueB));
    }else{
        alert("Enter a value for to the calculation!");  
        }
});
```

```html
A: <input id="valueA"> <br>
B: <input id="valueB"> <br>
<button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
```